# Error encountered when using Autodock/Vina Plugin in PyMOL

Tags: plugins, pymol

I am a beginner to PyMOL and I am using it for my docking project. I have encountered errors using the Autodock/Vina plugin in PyMOL.

I was trying to carry out the set up for the grid and Error 1 occurred when I was clicking on the arrow that allows me to change the grid parameter x,y and z.

As for Error 2, it occurs when I tried to generate the receptor on the next page.

Under the log section, I also got a notice saying "Batch: prepare_receptor4.py -r C:\Users\User\Desktop\plugin-test\receptor.3ig7.pdb -o C:\Users\User\Desktop\plugin-test\receptor.3ig7.pdbqt -A checkhydrogen"

It would be appreciated if you would tell me what is missing or should be done to solve these errors.

I look forward to reading any of your replies and I thank you in advance,

Elayne

```
Error: 1
TypeError Exception in Tk callback
  Function: <bound method Autodock.n_points_Y_changed of <pmg_tk.startup.autodock_plugin.Autodock object at 0x0000020649CD9388>> (type: <class 'method'>)
  Args: ('scroll', '1', 'units')
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\site-packages\Pmw.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: n_points_Y_changed() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Error: 2
FileNotFoundError Exception in Tk callback
  Function: <bound method Autodock.generate_receptor of <pmg_tk.startup.autodock_plugin.Autodock object at 0x0000020649CD9388>> (type: <class 'method'>)
  Args: ()
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\site-packages\Pmw.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\site-packages\pmg_tk\startup\autodock_plugin.py", line 1940, in generate_receptor
    result, output = getstatusoutput(command)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\site-packages\pmg_tk\startup\autodock_plugin.py", line 85, in getstatusoutput
    p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Schrodinger\PyMOL2\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also encountering the same issue on Windows, try running a linux distro on vmware and make sure to install Pymol with support for Python 2.7 because the script is not compatible with Python3.